# Best practice for sharing translation of Active Record attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization, yaml, rails-activerecord

I have the following yaml in one of my translation files:

```
se:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        name: "Namn"
        town: "Stad"
      admin:
        name: "Namn"
        level: "Nivå"
      pet:
        name: "Namn"
      company:
        name: "Namn"
      food:
        name: "Namn"
```

Is there a way for me to DRY this up and share the translation of `name` across all models? Bonus points if I can remove the entries for `pet`, `company` and `food` completely.

Comment: what do you mean by sharing name here?

Comment: Not having to write it for every model I have. Having it in only one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
se:
  common: &common
    name: "Namn"
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        <<: *common
        town: "Stad"
      admin:
        <<: *common
        level: "Nivå"
      pet:
        <<: *common
      company:
        <<: *common
      food:
        <<: *common
```

Comment: It did, but I was hoping that there would be a way to get rid of the `pet` entry.

Comment: so you don't want the pet entry? you can do it like this pet: *common

Comment: But I have several entries like `pet`. I'll update my post so you can see what I mean.